# image_view stereo_view do not show image or disparity

Tags: rviz, camera-info-manager, image-view, image-transport, stere-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to view my stereo disparity image using `image_view stereo_view` but whenever i run it i get two blank left and right windows with the following error in terminal

> init done
> opengl support available

(stereo_view:14758): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid uninstantiatable type '(null)' in cast to 'GtkWidget'

(stereo_view:14758): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: instance of invalid non-instantiatable type '(null)'

(stereo_view:14758): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(stereo_view:14758): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid uninstantiatable type '(null)' in cast to 'GtkWidget'

(stereo_view:14758): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: instance of invalid non-instantiatable type '(null)'

(stereo_view:14758): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(stereo_view:14758): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid uninstantiatable type '(null)' in cast to 'GtkWidget'

(stereo_view:14758): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: instance of invalid non-instantiatable type '(null)'

(stereo_view:14758): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
[ INFO] [1453739975.777426383]: Subscribing to:

```
* /camera/left/image_rect_color
* /camera/right/image_rect_color
* /camera/disparity
```

- I was able to get the images in rviz using `camera` display
- I am using ubuntu 14.04 with indigo distro
- how can i fix this problem?

**anybody please help me**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225012/image_view-stereo_view-do-not-show-image-or-disparity/) by [Azharudeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/23697/azharudeen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2016-01-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on 2016-03-17**:
Have you solved this?

**Comment by [sophie.shin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29160/sophie.shin/) on 2017-04-21**:
Did you solve this problem? can you please share the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running the same setup.

The problem is inside  imageCB() method in stereo_view.cpp.

image_mutex_.unlock() was being called before imshow() for the left, right and disparity images.

```
image_mutex_.unlock();
if (!last_left_image_.empty())
  cv::imshow("left", last_left_image_);
if (!last_right_image_.empty())
  cv::imshow("right", last_right_image_);
cv::imshow("disparity", disparity_color_);
```

the location of  `image_mutex_.unlock();`  is causing the window threads to lock up.

change the above to this:

```
if (!last_left_image_.empty())){
  cv::imshow("left", last_left_image_);
  cv::waitKey(1);
}
if (!last_right_image_.empty()){
  cv::imshow("right", last_right_image_);
  cv::waitKey(1);
}
cv::imshow("disparity", disparity_color_);
cv::waitKey(1);   

image_mutex_.unlock();
```

moving the unlock() command below the Mat checks and adding  `cv::waitKey(1)`  for each cv::imshow() solved it for me.

You'll have to download the source code from  https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline.git and compile it yourself. look in image_view/src/stereo_view.cpp for the image call back.

Hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [mtbrobotanist](https://answers.ros.org/users/26344/mtbrobotanist/) with karma: 76 on 2016-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-03-20**:
If there is not already a github issue for this, please open one.

**Comment by [mtbrobotanist](https://answers.ros.org/users/26344/mtbrobotanist/) on 2016-03-20**:
Done: https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/issues/188

**Comment by [sophie.shin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29160/sophie.shin/) on 2017-04-21**:
Can you please explain this in detail...?